# dc.js How to change dynamically the dimension of a chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm new with dc.js and I try to add a select input to the chart, and draw it depending on the entries. (the user select axis)
I draw initially someting :

```
  barChart
      .width(500)
      .height(500)
      .margins({left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
      .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([1880,1909]))
      .brushOn(true)
      .dimension(runDimension)
      .group(speedSumGroup);
```

and want to change the chart on input change. I have done someting like this, but nothing happens. (I also tried dc.redrawAll, without succes)

```
$("#mySelect1").on("change", function(){
        axis1=$('#mySelect1').find(":selected").text();
        runDimension4  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d[axis1];}),

        barChart
        .dimension(runDimension4)
        dc.renderAll();
});
```

Can someone explain me how to modify my charts and why my solution doesn't work?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to group the dimension again, e.g. runDimension4.group().reduceSum() - depending on your data.